# Shortcut to VBE not working in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

Alt + F11 is not opening the Visual Basic Editor in Excel 2016.  I am running on a laptop and have verified

1. Function Key is toggled to allow F keys
2. F11 by itself work to insert a chart
3. Alt Key works
4. Editor is accessible via Developer Ribbon
5. All other programs are shut down but Excel

I use this shortcut key all the time on my desktop and other laptop.  Something on this laptop seems to be causing issue.

Comment: Is there a keyboard remapping script running, such as with AutoHotKey?  Does booting [Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/) and/or [Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-Office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-Windows-PC-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72) in safe mode make a difference?  What about opening the VBE programmatically with `Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True` ?

Comment: At one stage I spent ages swearing at my computer because Shift-F9 didn't work to recalculate a worksheet, until I realised that SnagIt was intercepting the keystroke.

Comment: Exactly -- My Alt+F11 is mapped to mute my speakers.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you have Nvidia GeForce Experience. Change your keyboard shortcuts there. That was the issue with me.

Comment: That should be the accepted answer, Geoforce experience had it captured.

Answer (score 0):

I've just discovered that F.lux ( application to adjust screen brightness) is intercepting Alt + F11. When I turned it off VBE opens just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and fixed it by unplugging my USB keyboard, and plugging it back in. I occasionally get keyboard issues that can be fixed like that.